# How to randomly shuffle a deck of cards among players?

Tags: python, list, loops, random, list-comprehension

I am having trouble using one function in another to deal cards. Here is what I have so far.

```
import random as rand 

def create(): 
     ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']   
     suites = ['H', 'C', 'D', 'S'] 
     deck = [[r + s] for s in suites for r in ranks]    
     return deck   

def cards_dealt (num_cards, num_players, deck): 
     rand.shuffle(deck) 


print(cards_dealt(5, 3, deck))
```

I understand that the function is incomplete. I need num_cards to be the number of cards that each player receives, num_players to be the number of players, and deck to be the list of card strings from the function create(). 
For example, the print statement would reveal the 5 cards each of the three players gets from the list deck that has been shuffled. My problem is that whenever I write something, it says that deck is not defined.

Comment: `deck` is a local variable in the function `create`. It is not visible outside of the function. You must either make it global or return it. Back to your Python 101.

Comment: But I did return it? That's why I'm confused.

Comment: But you never assigned it to anything.

Comment: @DyZ `create` ends in `return deck`. `cards_dealt` has a parameter named `deck`. The thing that's missing is a call to `create` somewhere in the code.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not calling your create() function, you just define it, add a simple `deck = create()` before the printing. I have to note however the use of the same variable name inside and outside the function is not encouraged, as it can lead to confusion later in regards to scope of the variable, but it will do in your example.

Comment: As a hint for how to solve the next problem: dealing is basically just grouping the deck into equal-sized chunks (except with some left over). There are already a bunch of questions on Stack Overflow with great answers on that, and it should be pretty easy to adapt one of them to your program.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about your two functions, since they're both correct, and look at your top-level code:

```
import random as rand
def ...
def ...
print(cards_dealt(5, 3, deck))
```

Where does `deck` come from? Nowhere. Hence the exception.

It's pretty obvious where you *intended* it to come from—you have a `create` function that ends with a `return deck`. You just aren't calling it anywhere.

So you want:

```
import random as rand
def ...
def ...
deck = create()
print(cards_dealt(5, 3, deck))
```

… or, if you want to make it clearer that the global variable is unrelated to the two locals:

```
import random as rand
def ...
def ...
mydeck = create()
print(cards_dealt(5, 3, mydeck))
```

… or, if you want to make things more concise:

```
import random as rand
def ...
def ...
print(cards_dealt(5, 3, create()))
```

---

Beyond this problem, `cards_dealt` doesn't have a `return`, so it just returns `None`. When your function is complete, there might be something worth printing out, but for now, while you're debugging what you have so far, it's not very useful.

Meanwhile, if you want to print the shuffled deck, which *could* be useful, you'd do something like this:

```
import random as rand
def ...
def ...
mydeck = create()
cards_dealt(5, 3, mydeck)
print(mydeck)
```

When you later finish the function so it returns, say, a tuple of 3 lists of 5 cards, you'll probably want to store those return values for later as well as printing them, so it might go something like this:

```
import random as rand
def ...
def ...
mydeck = create()
hands = cards_dealt(5, 3, mydeck)
for hand in hands:
    print(hand)
```

Comment: They are both almost correct, cards_dealt has no return value.

Comment: Or just qualify that statement. I like your approach to explaining it.

Comment: Looks good, here's what I'd put for card_dealt if you want to add it. `rand.shuffle(deck) ` then  `return [deck[i:i+5] for i in range(0, num_cards*num_players, num_cards)]`

Comment: @Zev I don't want to write all of the OP's code for them, just show how to solve the problem they asked about.

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest an object-oriented approach where we will define the classes `Card`, `Deck` and `Player`.

Using objects instead of lists of cards will provide a neat API to implement games. As you implement game logic, it will also make it easier to keep a *single source of truth* as to where each card is and which player has each card.

## Deck API

```
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self, kind, rank, deck):
        self._kind = kind
        self._rank = rank
        self.deck = deck
        self.where = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Card(kind={}, rank={}'.format(self.kind, self.rank)

    @property
    def kind(self):
        return self._kind

    @property
    def rank(self):
        return self._rank


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        kinds = ['H', 'C', 'D', 'S']
        self.cards = [Card(kind, rank, self) for kind in kinds for rank in ranks]

    def deal(self, players, n=None):
        if any(p.deck is not self for p in players):
            raise RuntimeError('Player {} is not playing the deck'.format(p.id))

        n = n if n is not None else len(self.cards)
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

        for i, card in enumerate(self.cards[:n * len(players)]):
            card.where = players[i % len(players)]


class Player:
    def __init__(self, id, deck):
        self.id = id
        self.deck = deck

    @property
    def hand(self):
        return [card for card in deck.cards if card.where is self]
```

### Dealing cards

```
deck = Deck()
players = [Player(id, deck) for id in range(3)]

deck.deal(players, n=4)

for p in players:
    print(p.hand)
```

#### Output

```
[Card(kind=D, rank=A), Card(kind=D, rank=2), Card(kind=S, rank=5), Card(kind=S, rank=K)]
[Card(kind=S, rank=9), Card(kind=D, rank=5), Card(kind=C, rank=A), Card(kind=C, rank=Q)]
[Card(kind=C, rank=9), Card(kind=S, rank=J), Card(kind=D, rank=3), Card(kind=H, rank=9)]
```

### Playing a card

The `card.where` attribute can be updated to indicate the position of a card. Since it is the *single source of truth* for card position, this updates the `player.hand` property.

```
deck = Deck()
players = [Player(id, deck) for id in range(2)]

deck.deal(players, n=1)

players[0].hand[0].where = players[1]

for p in players:
    print(p.hand)
```

#### Output

```
[]
[Card(kind=H, rank=K), Card(kind=D, rank=2)]
```

### More features

The above API provides the basics to deal cards and move cards from hand to hand, but can be extended to implement new features.

Comment: Uhm, why? This is clearly much more advanced than the OP currently is

Comment: Sure, but implementing card games solely with lists and dicts almost always ends up in hard to track bugs due to having multiple sources of truth. While it is more advanced than where OP is, the title *How to randomly shuffle a deck of cards among players?* might very well attract other users that are looking for ideas of card deck implementation. Also, it is common on SO to have sidenote-like questions like this one that lie at the bottom of the answer pile, but are still good as sidenotes that address peripheral issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly other ways to do it, but you could complete your function as so, in order to return a dictionary of your players and their hands:

```
def cards_dealt(num_cards, num_players, deck):
    rand.shuffle(deck)
    return {player:[deck.pop() for _ in range(num_cards)] for player in range(num_players)}
```

Then, **create your deck** (that is where your *"deck is not defined"* problem comes in) and call your function:

```
my_deck = create()

print(cards_dealt(5, 3, my_deck))
```

Which returns:

```
{0: [['10S'], ['8S'], ['7D'], ['6S'], ['4C']], 
 1: [['JD'], ['AC'], ['QD'], ['2D'], ['JS']], 
 2: [['6D'], ['4H'], ['AS'], ['4S'], ['9S']]}
```

The equivalent `cards_dealt` function, but with loops instead of the dict and list comprehensions is:

```
def cards_dealt (num_cards, num_players, deck): 
     rand.shuffle(deck)
     player_hands = {i:[] for i in range(num_players)}
     for player in range(num_players):
         for num in range(num_cards):
             player_hands[player].append(deck.pop())
     return player_hands
```

Comment: Why does it return a dictionary instead of a list of lists?

Comment: IMO, it's a much neater way to organize things than a list of lists

Comment: Hm, okay. I just don't know how to go about finishing the rest when its not in lists. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: If you assign `player_hands = cards_dealt(5,3,my_deck)`, you can access the cards of a given player, say player 1 with : `player_hands[1]`