# OOP Deck of Cards in Python

Tags: python, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have been trying to learn object oriented programming in Python, and would like to start by programming card games. I have in mind to try coding several different games, so I wanted to start with a deck class that could be called for whatever game(s) I try to make.

I can get the basic behavior through functions, and I have no idea how to make it into a class. I first came up with this:

```
class Deck:

    def shuffle():
        cards = []
        suits = ['H', 'D', 'S', 'C']
        for suit in suits:
            for i in range(1, 14):
                cards.append((i, suit))
        shuf_deck = random.sample(cards, len(cards))
        return shuf_deck
```

The above works, but it just isn't very good. It's just a function, for one thing, that does two things, creating the deck and shuffling it; it seems these ought to be distinct. It sure seems like creating the deck to start with is a good job for an `__init__` function. Based on [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42107/simple-card-game-to-learn-oop), I got this together:

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds,' 'Spades', 'Clubs']
        self.values = range(1, 14)
        self.cards = []
        for Card in itertools.product(self.suits, self.values):
            self.cards.append(Card)

    def shuffle():
        # Not quite sure what to do here yet
        return self.cards

deck = Deck()
print(deck)
```

But this doesn't work. The code within the `__init__` function successfully creates the deck, but I can't quite get it 'objectified'. I've tried it several different ways, and it either returns something like `<__main__.Deck object at 0x7f56969f5630>`, which I believe is the memory address of the object itself, or I get some kind of error, invalid syntax, attribute error, etc. I can't seem to get the data from `__init__`; when I try to return data directly from `__init__` I get an error, and whenever I try to get that data from another method in the class I get errors too. Could someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Here is an answer I posted on some other question, you might help yourself from it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770568/5079316

Comment: What do you mean by _"I can't quite get it 'objectified'"_? `<__main__.Deck object at 0x7f56969f5630>` is the representation of your `Deck` object. Now, the question is what do you want to do with the deck object. You could implement a method to shuffle it and one to iterate through its cards etc.

Comment: What I mean by 'objectified' is that, even though I conceptually understand that the result should be something that looks like @OlivierMelançon 's Deck API, I can't even remotely begin to make even a bad version work. I just end up with a function or series of functions that happen to be in a class declaration, and not a real 'objectified' model of the object; I'm not sure how to say it more preceisely.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon what you have going on here is exactly what I've had in mind to make, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it. Thank you for such a thorough answer; it also seems to answer the next dozen or so questions I am sure to have.

Answer (score 2):

`deck` is the actual `Deck` object. `print(deck)` will give you the memory address of the object.

By "get the data from `__init__`", I believe you are interested in fetching the attributes:

```
deck.suits # this will give you ['Hearts', 'Diamonds,' 'Spades', 'Clubs']
deck.values # this will be [1,2, ..13]
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Cool, this answers my question about __init__. What I mean by "get the data" is just to be able to do stuff to it in methods and return values. Thank you!